# cannot resolve symbol 'view' at the line 'viewHolder.itemClickListener=(ItemClickListener)(view, position);{'

Tags: android

cannot resolve symbol 'view' at the line 'viewHolder.itemClickListener=(ItemClickListener)(view, position);{'.Whats the problem to my coding any idea?

```
private void updateList() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> userOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setQuery(counterRef,User.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(userOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull final User model) {
                if(!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()))
                    viewHolder.txtEmail.setText(model.getEmail()+"(me)");
                else
                    viewHolder.txtEmail.setText(model.getEmail());

                //we need implement item click f recycler view

                viewHolder.itemClickListener=(ItemClickListener)(view, position);{
                //if model is current user, not set click event
                if (!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())) {
                    Intent map = new Intent(ListOnline.this, MapTracking.class);
                    map.putExtra("email", model.getEmail());
                    map.putExtra("lat", mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                    map.putExtra("lng", mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                    startActivity(map);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use component id after viewHolder:

```
             viewHolder.YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME(LIKE EDITTEXT).itemClickListener=(ItemClickListener)(view, position);{
                //if model is current user, not set click event
                if (!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())) {
                    Intent map = new Intent(ListOnline.this, MapTracking.class);
                    map.putExtra("email", model.getEmail());
                    map.putExtra("lat", mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                    map.putExtra("lng", mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                    startActivity(map);
                }
```

Comment: because you are not implementing in correct way use addOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the view class Into your class... If not import it

Answer (score 0):

```
//Resolved by implementing setOnClickListener of the root View
viewHolder.txtEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
              if(!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())){

                       ......
              } 
        }
  }
```